# Output from second method not shown

Tags: java

I have developed a code to print 2 diamonds and the code is:

```
public class Diamond {
public static final int DIAMOND_SIZE = 5;

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Diamond Height: " + DIAMOND_SIZE);
    System.out.println("Output for: For Loop");

    int noOfRows = DIAMOND_SIZE;

    //Getting midRow of the diamond
    int midRow = (noOfRows)/2;

    //Initializing row with 1
    int row = 1;

    //Printing upper half of the diamond
    for (int i = midRow; i > 0; i--)
    {
        //Printing i spaces at the beginning of each row
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        //Printing j *'s at the end of each row
        for (int j = 1; j <= row; j++) {
            System.out.print("* ");
        }

        System.out.println();

        //Incrementing the row
        row++;
    }

    //Printing lower half of the diamond
    for (int i = 0; i <= midRow; i++) {
        //Printing i spaces at the beginning of each row
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        //Printing j *'s at the end of each row
        int mid = (row+1) / 2;
        for (int j = row; j > 0; j--) {
        if(i==0 && j==mid) {
            System.out.print("o ");
        }
        else {
            System.out.print("* ");
        }
        }

        System.out.println();

        //Decrementing the row
        row--;
    }
}

public static void diamond2() {
        // writing the top portion of the diamond
        int y = DIAMOND_SIZE;
        int i = 1;
        while (i < y + 1) {
              int spaces = 0;
              while (spaces < y - i) {
                    spaces++;
                    System.out.print(" ");
              }
              int j = i;
              while (j > 0) {
                    j--;
                    System.out.print("* ");
              }
              System.out.println();
              i++;
        }

        // writing the bottom half of the diamond
        i = y - 1;
        while (i > 0) {
              int spaces = 0;
              while (spaces < y - i) {
                    spaces++;
                    System.out.print(" ");
              }
              int j = i;
              while (j > 0) {
                    System.out.print("* ");
                    j--;
              }
              System.out.println();
              i--;
        }
}
}
```

The result I get from this is:

```
Diamond Height: 5
Output for: For Loop
  * 
 * * 
* o * 
 * * 
  *
```

Which is from the first method, the output from the second method is not showing. When I comment out the first method then the output of the second method is showing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to actually call `diamond2` to get it to do anything.

Comment: I dont understand your question. You are not calling the second method, so how could it do anything? You need to call it from within your main method?!

Comment: Type `diamond2();` under the end brace for the for loop  referecned by the comment `//Printing lower half of the diamond` in your `main` method or better yet convert the code for `diamond1` into its own method aswell and only have the two lines in your `main` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access the chunk of code that is your second method, you need to formally call the method header. In your case, it can be done like so

```
diamond2();
```

Add this line of code into your main method where you would like that method to be called.